# Is constexpr really needed in c++ in general?

Tags: c++, constexpr

There are exist question with similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016771/is-constexpr-really-needed/57126140#57126140). But my question in another aspect.

My question about constexpr in c++ in general. I think that there must be requirement for the compilers, that any expression/statement/etc that could be done in compile time - is **must** be done in compile time. The compiler better know which things it could make during compilation.

Instead committee pull compiler-specific things to the user space. I think it is mistake.

Is exist some reasons to manage manually the compiler from the user code?

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/q/39795170/103167

Comment: If you do much template code you'll likely use it every day. I do at least. It's needed for SFINAE and constexpr if (which is sort of like more readable SFINAE)

Comment: @Cruz Jean, my point, that [constexpr if] is redundant - if your expression could be done during compilation - it _must_ be done during compilation. Do you know some cases where compiler cant made such optimization?

Comment: @AeroSun The branch not taken in a constexpr if is not compiled. period. thus it is allowed to contain things that would otherwise be compile errors, such as using `T::S` where no such `S` exists within `T`. That couldn't be done with a normal if, since both branches of an if must be valid (regardless of whether one of them can be optimized away).